# how to make Curl request on Angular 2

Tags: visual-studio, angular, curl, typescript

I´m new to Angular 2 and I would like to make curl request

```
$ curl -u okmAdmin:admin -H "Accept: application/json" \
   http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/folder/getChildren?fldId=3492d662-b58e-417c-85b6-930ad0c6c3cf
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: looks like a standard http get request with username/password auth header

Comment: @suraj can you give me an example pls? i saw some examples of http request, but no one with  username/password